# Custom Camera using surface view Holder Class

Tags: android, camera

I am trying to implement custom camera using surface view holder, but the brightness is so low, and I am not able to make the brightness as the native camera has, no solution found so far, please help. Tried getting system brightness as well, but it does not appear to be on camera view.

**Sample Code:**

```
private void setUpCamera(Camera c) {

        Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
        Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
        rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        int degree = 0;
        switch (rotation) {
            case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                degree = 0;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                degree = 90;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                degree = 180;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                degree = 270;
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
        if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            // frontFacing
            rotation = (info.orientation + degree) % 330;
            rotation = (360 - rotation) % 360;
        } else {
            // Back-facing
            rotation = (info.orientation - degree + 360) % 360;
        }
           Camera.Parameters params = c.getParameters();
          params.set("iso", 400);

         c.setDisplayOrientation(rotation);
       c.setParameters(params);
        showFlashButton(params);
    }
}
```

Comment: Any solution for this issue?

Comment: Which device is this?

Comment: Lenovo TAB 3 7 Marshmallow.

Comment: I don't see any solution on brightness, surface view's brightness is very low, even in bright light.

Comment: Try to switch to OpenGL TextureSurface. This gives you more control, e.g. you can 'brighten' the texture using a simple shader.

Comment: Will do thanks Alex.